# how to find out the total bandwidth of guard nodes in Tor network?

Tags: guard, bandwidth

I want to know the total bandwidth of the guard nodes. I went through https://metrics.torproject.org/network.html#bandwidth but I saw only the graphs. I want to know the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the advertised bandwidth values in the [bandwidth.csv file](https://metrics.torproject.org/stats/bandwidth.csv), which is   linked below each metric graph.

As explained on the [Tor Metrics Portal: Statistics page](https://metrics.torproject.org/stats.html#bandwidth), each row of this file has the following fields:

`date,isexit,isguard,advbw,bwread,bwwrite,dirread,dirwrite`

The rows where `isguard` column  is **t**(rue) will give you the bandwidth for the guard nodes.

Please note that there are two rows where `isguard` is  equal to **t** for each day: one for the `Guard-only` nodes and the other for the `Guard & Exit` nodes. So you just need to add them to get the total value.

> 2014-03-25,f,f,1004882359,277531964,294481782,,
>   2014-03-25,f,**t**,4561740723,2477486643,2592422620,,  `# Guard-only`
>   2014-03-25,t,f,460279098,202651074,207583594,,
>   2014-03-25,t,**t**,2467664369,1416232643,1461686772,,  `# Guard & Exit`
>   2014-03-25,,,8494566550,4374045598,4556230558,4666714,141124165